# Why must the key of an NSDictionary conform to NSCopying

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nscopying

I noticed that for an object to be a key for an `NSDictionary` it must conform to `NSCopying`.

Why is this so? I would understand that all keys must implement `hash`, but why `NSCopying`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the keys *are* copied. You wouldn't want a key to be stored as a reference to the very same object you started with, would you? It would be terrible if `d[myThing] = myValue` retained a reference to a *possibly mutable* instance `myThing`. That would mean that the dictionary could get mutated behind its own back.

Comment: Shouldn't the same logic apply to the values then?

Comment: Just to give an extreme example, imagine two keys being mutated so as make their hash values the same - thus violating the entire structure of the dictionary.

Comment: No because mutation of a value does not destroy the _structure_ of the dictionary. The structure depends upon the stability of the keys. Of course _you_ are free to copy a value on assignment, and there are certainly situations where you should do so, but you don't have to.

Comment: out of curiosity, any example of object that doesn't conform to NSCopying and therefore can't be a key?

Comment: The docs actually tell you all about this. Look under [`dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:), for example.

Comment: Any object that you declare yourself, like `myThing` in my example. It is a Thing, which is a subclass of NSObject. NSObject does not conform to NSCopying and so neither does Thing - unless I make it do so.

Comment: I know the answer is old but I am wondering why NSMutableSet won't has the same restriction of NSCoping on its objects

Answer (score 6):

`NSDictionary` guaranties that if you store a value with some key `x` this key is **fixed** and you can retrieve this value with the equivalent key `y` (`y.isEqual(x) == YES`). There are only two possibilities to do so:

1. Copy keys to prevent them from changing.
2. Demand that keys are immutable.

Apple decided that for most cases coping keys is better.

In case you need a dictionary were keys are not copied (for example keys do not implement NSCopying or coping is too expensive) you can use [NSMapTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/index.html).
For example you can use

```
[NSMapTable strongToStrongObjectsMapTable]
```

to store keys and values as a strong references.